# Definitions of Sierpinski Carpet and Higher Dimensional Analogues

Tags: measure-theory, fractals

We define the Cantor Set as:

$Let \mathscr{J} := \{ 0, 2, \ldots , 3^{m-1} -1 \}$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$, then 
$$C = [0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{k \in \mathscr{J}} \Big( \frac{3k+1}{3^{m}} , \frac{3k +2}{3^m} \Big)$$

is it proper to define the sierpinski carpet and menger sponge, and their higher dimensional analogues as $C \times C$, $C \times C \times C$, and $\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} C_i$ respectively?

I cannot seem to find an explicit formula for higher dimensionl analogues on the internet. Additionally, I'd like to know what it would mean to discuss the cantor set iterated a hyperreal number of times. i.e. 
$Let \mathscr{J} := \{ 0, 2, \ldots , 3^{m-1} -1 \}$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, then 
$$C = [0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}^{*}} \bigcup_{k \in \mathscr{J}} \Big( \frac{3k+1}{3^{m}} , \frac{3k +2}{3^m} \Big)$$

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated, especially on the second portion of the question.

Comment: No. They are a bit different things.

Comment: @Berci How would one properly define these then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to generalize what is removed in the cantor set.

The Sierpinski carpet is

$$S = [0,1]\times [0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \left \{ \bigcup_{k,l \in \mathscr{J}} \Big( \frac{3k+1}{3^{m}} , \frac{3k +2}{3^m}\Big)\times \Big( \frac{3l+1}{3^{m}} , \frac{3l +2}{3^m}\Big)\right \} $$

The Menger sponge is similar but more complicated, as we remove pieces on the edge.

Your second construction has a simple description. The regular Cantor set is the set of all ternary numbers between 0 and 1 that have a representation using only the digits 0 and 2. Your set is the same, but allowing the ternary representation to have a non standard integer number of digits.

For instance, for a nonstandard $m$, $$ \bigcup_{k \in \mathscr{J}} \Big( \frac{3k+1}{3^{m}} , \frac{3k +2}{3^m} \Big)$$ is the set of all ternary numbers all of whose representations have a 1 in the $m$th 'ternary place'.

But decimal or ternary numbers need care in hyperreal numbers:http://www.cut-the-knot.org/WhatIs/Infinity/9999.shtml

Comment: So it is not proper to define it as  $$M = [0,1] \times [0,1]\times [0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \left \{ \bigcup_{k,l,r \in \mathscr{J}} \Big( \frac{3k+1}{3^{m}} , \frac{3k +2}{3^m}\Big)\times \Big( \frac{3l+1}{3^{m}} , \frac{3l +2}{3^m}\Big) \times  \Big( \frac{3r+1}{3^{m}} , \frac{3r +2}{3^m}\Big) \right \} $$

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would work,  but you have to let one of the factors be all of [0,1].

Comment: One of which factors? The three $k,l,r$?

Comment: One of the three open intervals should be replaced by the whole interval [0,1].

Comment: And why is this?

Comment: Because instead of removing each center cube, you are removing it plus all of its neighbors. On https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge, note how each hole goes all the way through the sponge. In the first stage, you remove (1/3,2/3)x(1/3,2/3)x[0,1] and (1/3,2/3)x[0,1]x(1/3,2/3) and [0,1]×(1/3,2/3)x(1/3,2/3)

Comment: Ahh, I understand. So do you have any comments on the second half of my question?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter edited accordingly.

Comment: If you could elaborate a little on the second portion, I'd gladly award the bounty.